# Автоматическое определение имени переменной, python aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

пишу бота с использованием aiogram
пытаюсь в одной функции реализовать диалог с пользователем
мне нужно задать несколько разных вопросов пользователю и сохранить результат
считаю будет неправильно создавать отдельную функцию для каждого вопроса

не пойму как автоматически подставить нужную переменную для сохранения данных

или может есть более простое решение моей задачи?

```
class DataTask(StatesGroup):
    create_task = State()


async def cmd_task(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await DataTask.create_task.set()
    await state.update_data(counter = 0)
    await state.update_data(items = [['Введите название задачи','title'],
                                     ['Введите описание','description'],
                                     ['Укажите дату окончания','date_over']])
    #await state.update_data(title = '')
    #await state.update_data(description = '')
    #await state.update_data(date_over = '')


async def task_work(messasge: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    data = await state.get_data()
    await messasge.reply(f"{data['items'][data['counter']][0]}")
    await state.update_data(counter = data['counter']+1)
    #await state.update_data(exec(%s = %s %  (data['items'][data['counter'][1]], message.text)))
    if data['counter']+1 == (len(data['items'])):
        await state.update_data(counter = 0)
        await state.reset_state(with_data=False)


async def mtest(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    data = await state.get_data()
    await message.reply(f"{data['title']}\n"
                         f"{data['description']}\n"
                         f"{data['counter']}"
                         f"{data['date_over']}")


def register_handlers_todo(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(cmd_task, commands="newtask", state='*')
    dp.register_message_handler(mtest, commands='test',state='*')
    dp.register_message_handler(task_work,
                                content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT,
                                state=DataTask.create_task)
```

Comment: https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial-2/fsm/

Comment: прекрасный учебник